# Visualize each row of pandas data frame as a tree

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tree

I have a data frame having 4 columns A, B, C, D. I need to visualize/ print each row of my data frame as a **tree** structure.

Example:

df['A'] = franchisee

df['B'] = sign off

df['C'] = status

df['D'] = registration

Then, I need to visualize this row as a tree where franchisee is the parent node of sign off, sign off is the parent node of status and child node of franchisee, status is the parent node of registration and child node of sign off, registration is the child node of status.
How can I do that? I have tried using the anytree library:

```
from anytree import Node, RenderTree, NodeMixin
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file_location')
for i, j, k, l in zip(df['A'], df['B'], df['C'], df['D']):
    mdept = Node(a)
    dept = Node(b, parent = a)
    qtype = Node(c, parent = b)
    sqtype = Node(d, parent = c)
```

but it shows the following error:

Exception has occured:TreeError

Parent node 'franchisee' is not of type 'NodeMixin'.

Comment: please provide the output of `df.to_dict()` (or `df.head(10).to_dict()` if too many rows)

Comment: @mozway df.head().to_dict() gives the following output:

{'A': {0: 'Franchisee', 1: 'IT', 2: 'IT', 3: 'IT', 4: 'MO Genie'},
'B': {0: 'BO Franchisee ', 1: 'IT- Trading', 2: 'IT- Trading', 3: 'IT- Trading', 4: 'MO Genie'},
'C': {0: 'Status- BO Franchisee Sign Off', 1: 'BO- Usability ', 2: 'MOTrader- Unable to login', 3: 'MO Trader- Usability', 4: 'Reports/ Statements'},
'D': {0: 'Registration status', 1: 'BO- Usability', 2: 'Password Reset', 3: 'Usability', 4: 'CMR/ Client Master'}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know this library, so I can't ensure there is not a better way, but iterating trough the rows and columns and using a root node:

```
from anytree import Node
root = Node('root')
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    n = Node(row['A'], parent=root)
    for c in ['B', 'C', 'D']:
        n = Node(row[c], parent=n) # n is always the previous node

# export as dot graph
from anytree.exporter import DotExporter
DotExporter(root).to_picture('graph.png')
```

output:

[image]

Comment: thanks! worked like a charm, but for the entire dataset the png file is completely destroyed. I don't think there is a solution rather than breaking the dataset into smaller parts, right?

Comment: Yes probably, you can maybe save the 'subroot' nodes in a list instead and export the individual subgraphs?